# How do libraries/includes work?

Tags: compiling, shared-library

I'm trying to understand how libraries work. Here are some questions I have about it:

1. I downloaded a tarball and extracted it. When I do "./configure", it searches in pre-defined directories from what I understand for certain library files.

   What does it do then? It creates a makefile, and the makefile contains the paths
   to these libraries?

   Then I do "make", it compiles the source code and hard-codes the locations
   of the libraries? Am I correct?

   I do not really understand if libraries are files with pre-defined paths or the OS somehow gives access to the libraries through system calls.
2. I complied something on my computer than moved it to a remote
   server, the executable needs MySQL libraries to work, the server has MySQL
   but for some reason when executing the file it tells me "can't find libmysqlclient.so.16". Is there a solution for this? Is there a way to know
   where is tries to locate this file or give it another path?

   I can't compile it on the server since it has no compiler and I don't have
   root access to install packages.
3. Last question is if in the sequence "./configure","make","make install"
   the "make install" command is the only one that actually puts files
   outside the directory in which these files reside?

   If for example the software will be installed in /usr/local/ is the "make install"
   command the only one that will require "sudo" before it?

   Let me see if I got it correctly: "./configure" creates the Makefile according to the location of various files on your system. "make" compiles the source code according to this makefile. And "make install" moves the files to their appropriate location.

Thank you to those who had the patience to read my questions.

Comment: one more thing, the "./configure" command, does it overwrite the Makefile every time? if for example I run it and there's an error, can it cause any damage or once I fix the error it will just overwrite the Makefile and everything's OK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`configure` generates a `Makefile` and often other files, such as `config.cache`. The contents of these files is based on the options you pass to `configure` and on observing your system. For example, many programs have optional components, and `configure` looks for the dependencies of each component and generates a makefile that only builds the components for which you have all the dependencies.

If you run `configure` and then change your system configuration, you should do `make distclean` first (if the program follows the usual conventions), to remove the makefile and `configure`'s cache. Running `configure` again typically works when you want to pass it different arguments, but not when it's cached observations about your system.

Regarding libraries, the `configure` stage looks at what you have from a source compatibility point of view. If `libfoo2` is source-compatible with `libfoo3` but not with `libfoo1`, and you have `libfoo2`, then the resulting makefile will work build a binary linked against `libfoo2` or a binary linked against `libfoo3` but not a binary linked against `libfoo1` (compilation would fail due to the source-level incompatibility).

When the executable is compiled and linked, the version requirement becomes more precise: the resulting executable needs a binary-compatible library (same ABI, not just same API).

Executables don't hard-code full paths to libraries; they hard-code names of libraries (`-l` argument to the linker) and sometimes a runtime library search path (`-rpath`) that comes in addition to the default search path of the target system. Finding the libraries at run time is the job of the [dynamic linker](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/ld.so.8.html).

I recommend playing a little with `ldd` and `strace`. `ldd` shows the libraries required by an executable and where the system would find them. `strace` shows all the system calls that happen when a program is loaded; the first few come from the dynamic linker that loads the required libraries. Here are a few experiments whose results you should try to understand.

```
ldd /bin/true
strace /bin/true
perl -pe 's/libc\.so/libc.zz/' </bin/true >broken
chmod +x broken
ldd ./broken
strace ./broken
ln -s /lib/libc.so.6 libc.zz.6
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. strace ./broken
```

Summarizing the answers to your specific questions:

1. `configure` hard-codes source compatibility issues. The `make` step hard-codes binary compatibility issues. Library locations are determined at run time.
2. If only the location of the library has changed, the dynamic linker will typically find it (if you have a library installed in a non-standard location, pass the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable). If you have only a different version of the library, then it's not the same library; you need to either get a library with the ABI version that your program is compiled against, or compile your program against the ABI version for which you have the library installed.
3. `configure` determines the build configuration from what you have on your system and the arguments you pass. `make` builds the executable and other bits. `make install` copies the bits into place; only this stage might require elevated permissions (if you don't already have permission to write to the target directory, which you would e.g. if you were installing into your home directory).
4. `configure` overwrites the makefile, but just re-running `configure` doesn't start from scratch because it keeps a cache.

Comment: THANX A LOT for the detailed answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that when you ./configure on one computer, it derives a makefile specific for that one computer, then when you transfer the compiled program, the library is not where the makefile (or the executable) knew it was, so it throw out an error. As you can see that when you configure, not every library it checks for is required. So it must make a different makefile depending on your system. Another example of this is when you have a different architecture it requires different libraries, and so on.

And yes you have the order correct. 'make' is the safe command, only working in the current directory, sudo is basically required for 'make install'. It's bad to not have root privilages when installing software.

Comment: Do you know if the paths of the libraries are hard-coded into the exectuable? or is there something I can do, some command to make the file load a different library?